# linq select using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a class like this, a class List, a list of string list

```
class Test
{
    public string AAA{ get; set; }
    public string BBB{ get; set; }
}

List<Test> test;

List<List<string>> output;
```

I want put the content from test to output.
I am now using linq to transfer it as below.

```
output[0] = test.Select(x=>x.AAA).ToList();
output[1] = test.Select(x=>x.BBB).ToList();
```

If this class has 10 properties, I must write 10 line of code to transfer it.
I got a keyword "reflection" but I have no idea how to use it on my code.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What you want to do via reflection here is quite complicated - an advanced topic because a: you're working around generics (generics and reflection don't play nicely), and b: it involves LINQ expression trees or delegates. In this case, the 10 lines are probably a more maintainable option... are you sure you want to get into this?

Comment: I have many entity framework classes.I want insert huge data to table, I use oracle data binding.so I should create array for every field to set value to the OracleParameter.Value. the table may have many fields 10,15. I just want simplify my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request all properties with reflection as List and select those from the class list like this :

First one will give you 1 list per class with list of properties and value

```
var first = test.Select(t => t.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Select(p => p.GetValue(t, null).ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
```

this one will give you 1 list per property with list of class property value

```
var second typeof(Test).GetProperties().Select(p => test.Select(t => p.GetValue(t, null).ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all string properties:

```
        List<List<string>> output = new List<List<string>>();
        foreach(var property in typeof(Test).GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string)) continue;

            var getter = (Func<Test, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(Func<Test, string>), property.GetGetMethod());
            output.Add(test.Select(getter).ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too bad, I don't think:

```
var allObjects = new List<Test>();
var output = new List<List<string>>();

//Get all the properties off the type
var properties = typeof(Test).GetProperties();

//Maybe you want to order the properties by name?
foreach (var property in properties) 
{
    //Get the value for each, against each object
    output.Add(allObjects.Select(o => property.GetValue(o) as string).ToList());
}
```

Comment: The propertyInfo.GetValue() at least have two parameters ?

Comment: You shouldn't need two parameters... That code compiles & works for me, .Net 4.5

Comment: Got it ,I am using .Net 4.0. Microsoft overload this function at 4.5.Anyway thanks a lot.